# What effect does allowed length of text strings have on performance and size

Tags: database, performance, database-design, database-schema, diskspace

When I'm creating a database table (in my case its usually arcgis geodatabases, but I expect the issues are the same across all databases) I often find it difficult to accurately judge the required length of a text field so I overestimate it (50, or 100). Will this significantly affect the performance of, and disk space used, by the database? and are there any lenths that are particularly effiecient (like 8,16,32,64)?

Or should I continue to make my databases flexible?

Comment: This is highly vendor- and therefore product-specific - but in general: **yes**, larger string will hurt performance, just plain because more data needs to be shuffled around. And in general, no, there are no "magic" string lengths that have benefits for performance, like 15, 255 etc. - just define your string as long as you need them - but no longer than that!

Comment: To add to marc_s comment: One example on why this is DBMS dependent: in Postgres there is absolutely no difference whatsoever in the way the data is stored between `varchar(10)`, `varchar(7665)` and `text` (to allow "unlimited" values). For Oracle or SQL Server it does make a difference if you choose `varchar` (limited length) or `CLOB`/`varchar(max)` (unlimited length). There was a discussion on this on dba.stackexchange.com a while ago, but I can't find it anymore

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14375343/330315 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20974/1822 for DBMS specific discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are not really memory intensive, each char usually only exists out of 2 bytes (supporting every language) , the only reason why you should use shorter strings then longer ones if you are doing certain operations on them, because a string is generally just a array of characters and with bigger strings, bigger operations have to be done.

so in general, reserving 100 characters for a string results in 200 bytes which is 0.2KB , and with 1000 strings this is less then 0.2 MB, so this shouldn't really be any problem unless you are storing everything in RAM on a mini computer with 256MB ram.

Answer: Not a very big effect on size (realistically seen), medium effect on performance (in nanoseconds) because iterating each character and for example comparing with another one in a long string can be relatively intense, but nothing to worry about untill you are comparing thousands of strings with thousands of other strings